# Can I add a transparent logo to this material?

Tags: texturing, materials

This isn't my material, I downloaded it and I'd like to add a PNG logo over the top.

I'm hoping to be able to have the faces with the texture still be metallic looking, just with a logo over the top.

Can this be done? I have duplicated the material so I can make changes as needed. Thanks in advance for any help!

I'm using Cycles render engine

Material: 
[image: Image of my material nodes, where I would like to add an image texture]

Where I want my logo:
[image: Image of where I would like my logo to sit]

[Here is my original blender file (Google Drive)](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1HKu7Dd6ZYYX-FH6ga3naDJnhvGWYqfih)

Comment: Did you UV-unwrap your model ?